# How to Log a Loop inside Eclipse Console (Java)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, logging, console

I am using Eclipse with Java and the Android SDK.

I have a while loop giving me issues and I need to see what it being logged in the if statement below (what is being added to the two ArrayLists).  This is the loop:

```
 while (totalDebt > 0) {

 // stuff

 if (totalDebt > 0) {
    debtList.add(totalDebt);
    feeList.add(interestFeeTotal);
 }

}
```

How can I use log to see what is going on here in each iteration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AT the top of your file you need to put

```
import android.util.log;
```

Then anywhere in that file you can write

```
Log.d("Tag","Message");
```

Where for message you can do something like

```
Log.d("Tag", String.format("Iteration(%d), added to the debtList", i);
```

assuming `i` is your iteration variable

Comment: Hey thanks; I actually re-edited my answer.  I stupidly didn't show the whole loop, and (doh!) it was a while loop... can you do the same with a while loop since it doesn't have an iteration variable?

Comment: Yeah, you can do the same, just print something like `Log.d("Tag", String.format("Current total debt: %f", totalDebt));`